# Combination of interpolation types for multivariate interpolation

Tags: interpolation

I have a N-dimensional dataset, for which I need to apply multivariate interpolation. Is there a possible way to use different kind of interpolation methods in different dimensions? I considered to do this since I want to reduce the overall interpolation error, by choosing the interpolation type for each dimension. So far I only found methods which use a single interpolation type (e.g. cubic spline, linear,...) for all dimensions (such as the Matlab function [interpn](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interpn.html) or the Scipy [libary](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html), ...). I'm already very thankful for a reference to literature, as I couldn't find anything.

Comment: First, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation

Comment: Thank you. However, this source also uses the same interpolation type in all dimensions, if I'm correct?

Comment: There is a bunch of different methods which are partly listed in the linked page.  Have also a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html This is a huge domain.

Comment: I'm familiar with multivariate interpolation in Matlab or using Scipy. Unfortunately,  the interpolation method cannot be set to be different for each dimension for this available code.